How to implement GMAIL API (with oauth) to send emails to user, in an ASP.NET Core 8 application
I'd like to understand how to connect the Gmail API to manage communications with users (email verification, updates, ...).
I'm struggling to find up-to-date documentation/tutorials about these topics.
I tried using the following NuGet packages: google.apis.auth, google.apis.gmail.v1. But, apparently, using google libraries compromise the cookie for identity authentication.

Are you using asp net sign-in or authorization in your application currently

Yes, I'm using identity authentication with cookies

Then don't use the Google apis library it will over write that cookie

Thanks Linda, what do you suggest to implement email sending via Gmail API and OAuth 2.0 (since the transition from "less secure" apps to OAuth)? Is there any .NET documentation I can read?
